# Why is NPE not reported on correct line

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

Running the following:

```
public class NPESample {

  String value;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NPESample npeSample = null;
    "foo"
        .replaceAll(
            "f",
            npeSample.value);
  }
}
```

Will give:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NPESample.main(NPESample.java:9)
```

Reported line (7) is the line `"foo"` and not the actual line where NPE happens (10) `npeSample.value`.

Why is this? I was caught by surprise when debugging code and thrown off by the "wrong" reported line number in the code.

To reproduce run this:

```
cat > ./NPESample.java <<DELIM
public class NPESample {

  String value;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NPESample npeSample = null;
    "foo"
        .replaceAll(
            "f",
            npeSample.value);
  }
}
DELIM

javac NPESample.java
java NPESample
```

output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NPESample.main(NPESample.java:7)
```

```
javac -version
javac 13.0.1
```

```
java -version
openjdk version "13.0.1" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221944/discussion-on-question-by-raipe-why-is-npe-not-reported-on-correct-line).

Answer (score 2):

This does not look like a bug, to me. Specifically, it seems that the mapping is freely allowed not be one-one, [as the SPEC says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12):

> That is, LineNumberTable attributes may together represent a given line of a source file, **and need not be one-to-one with source lines**.

Even `JDK-15` reports the wrong line:

> Cannot read field "value" because "npeSample" is null

on line `9`.